# Group By Problem.. on Retrieving Data from Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview

I am Beginner in Sql, I m trying SQL Group By statement, my requirement is below.

```
Table Structure  <br> 
USerID  int <br> 
BrowserName nvarchar(200) <br> 
BrowserVersion nvarchar <br> 
LoggedOntime  Time
```

here is my requirement. I want select the all details based on the user id along with it should Group By Browser Name.  I tried the follwing query its returining. but how to use this in visual studio to Display in Gridview as Group FOr each Browser. when the user Clicks a group in gridview it should display all details of that browser.

for eg. If i click FireFox then It should shows the detail for Firfox Group with all Version, And LoggedOnTime Details for the particular user id

```
select  
  BrowserName, 
  LoggedOnTime, 
  BrowserVersion
from 
  BrowserSession 
  inner join Users on UserId = Users.UsersId
where 
  UserId=21 
group by 
  BrowserName, 
  LoggedOnTime,
  BrowserVersion 
order by 
  BrowserName, 
  LoggedOnTime
```

Comment: Post the code where you are facing problem. Have you given a try binding the data to the grid?

Comment: I done Binding to Grid using Dataset and Data Adapter, now i want to Group in Grid view. but I am trying to Display in Grid View as A Group for Each Browser, means In GridView One Group for FireFox, one Group for GECKO, one Group IE. If u click IE, it should display all the details belonging to IE

Comment: You can create data grid for every group and insert into the parent grid. Bind the sub-data grid to the specific data group.

Comment: Can u Help me to do this.. I m trying it .. can u please help me...  How to do this, any tutorials, or codes please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the query is `static` you can do like this, otherwise you can use `parameters` on the query:

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        string sqlQuery = "select  BrowserName, LoggedOnTime, BrowserVersion"
                            + " from BrowserSession inner join Users on UserId=Users.UsersId"
                            + " where UserId=21 group by BrowserName, LoggedOnTime,BrowserVersion order by BrowserName, LoggedOnTime";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        adapter.Fill(ds, "TableName");

        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Using Parameters:

```
        string sqlQuery = "select  BrowserName, LoggedOnTime, BrowserVersion"
                            + " from BrowserSession inner join Users on UserId=Users.UsersId"
                            + " where UserId=@userID group by BrowserName, LoggedOnTime,BrowserVersion order by BrowserName, LoggedOnTime";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", 21);
```

Comment: I know this Method.. and even i can bind it to Data Grid. Thats not issue. but I am trying to Display in Grid View as A Group for Each Browser, means In GridView One Group for FireFox, one Group for GECKO, one Group IE. If u click IE, it should display all the details belonging to IE

Comment: group in the sense how? in collapse and expand manner? can you show any sample?

Answer (score 0):

You can create data grid for every group and insert into the parent grid. Bind the sub-data grid to the specific data group.

Here are few links.

1. [Step by step](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/01/building_a_grouping_grid_with.html) I was not able to access the live demo. This looks like what you want.
2. [4 Guys from Rolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020113733/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072603-1.aspx)
3. Report kind of layout in asp.net 1.1 [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/PrettyDatagrids.aspx)